# reuse content of part of url in html

Tags: javascript, url, twig

i would like to reuse parts of the url in the content of the webpage

as example
domain.com/specialist/brand/location/

where i want to reuse "brand" multiple times in the content of the webpage
and also "location" multiple times in the content of the webpage.

first i tried it with variables
url/?specialist=brand&bezorgen=city

but this does not work with the following method, because it renders them only once

i've tried the

```
<script>
    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    const specialist = urlParams.get('specialist');
    const bezorgen = urlParams.get('bezorgen');
    document.getElementById("specialist").innerHtml = specialist;
    document.getElementById("bezorgen").innerHtml = bezorgen;

</script>

and in the html

<span id=specialist></span>
<span id=bezorgen></span>
```

What would be the fastest way to get this working

technology = twig and js

Thanks in advance

Comment: Question is unclear. What is your expected output? What do you mean with `multiple` times

Comment: @DarkBee for example if the forelast and last part of the url are /brand/location/ 
we want to use that in the text on the page. there are now twig shortcode's {{ brand }} 
<p>this {{ brand }} bike is pretty awesome and we can deliver this at {{ location }}. This {{ brand }} is really trustworthy</p>

Comment: Are you using any framework or just standalone twig?

Comment: using a managed framework, partly closed source

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

### Twig

As you are using a custom framework I'd suggest you to mimick the `app.request.get` behavior that is available in `Symfony`.

**First create a class that delivers the same logic**

Request.php

```
class Request {
    public function __construct() {}

    public function get($key) {
        return isset($_GET[$key]) ? $_GET[$key] : null;
    }

    public function post($key) {
        return isset($_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$key] : null;
    }

    public function url() {
        $http = 'http'.(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? 's': '');
        return  $http.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
}
```

**Register the class in `twig`**

The easiest way to add an instance of the `Request` class is just to add it as a global

```
<?php
    ...
    $twig->addGlobal('app', [ 'request' => new Request(), ]);
```

**Access the class inside a template**

```
<p>this {{ app.request.get('brand') }} bike is pretty awesome and we can deliver this at {{ app.request.get('location') }}. This {{ app.request.get('brand') }} is really trustworthy</p>
```

---

*mandatory note*

Please be aware it is possible that clients will try to inject/generate unsafe output. However `twig` will prevent this as long as you don't mark the content as safe with e.g. the filter `raw`

Comment: unfortunately we are not allowed to use ANY php... thats why we were looking for strictly js solution...

Comment: Added JS answer. Also doing this in pure JS will certainly be unsafe, see my note in this answer

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript

The problem with your javascript is probably because you are creating elements with the same id over and over again, which is why only the first element with the correct id will be replaced correctly

An easy solution would be to switch to classes

```js
var foo = 'foo';
var bar = 'bar';

document.querySelectorAll('.foo').forEach(span => {
    span.innerHTML = foo;
});

document.querySelectorAll('.bar').forEach(span => {
    span.innerHTML = bar;
});
```

```css
span {
    display: block;
}

span + span {
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

span.foo {
    color: red;
}

span.bar {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<span class="foo"></span>
<span class="foo"></span>
<span class="bar"></span>
<span class="foo"></span>
<span class="foo"></span>
<span class="bar"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding, but the OP seems to ask two things: (1) how to extract info from the url -- either from within the path or the query, (2) how to alter the dom with that info.

Looking at (1), you can get a lot of information from the expression `new URL(window.location.href);`

```js
// using the path
// these window-named vars to simulate the browsers' window global
let windowA = {
  location: {
    href: "http://example.com/specialist/mybrand/mylocation"
  }
};
const urlA = new URL(windowA.location.href);
console.log(urlA.pathname.split('/').slice(-2));

// using the query
let windowB = {
  location: {
    href: "http://example.com/specialist/?brand=mybrand&location=mylocation"
  }
};
const urlB = new URL(windowB.location.href);
const params = [urlB.searchParams.get('brand'), urlB.searchParams.get('location')]
console.log(params);
```

Looking at (2), the OP code looks fine, except the div's ids need to be placed in quotes...

```js
let _window = {
  location: {
    href: "http://example.com/specialist/mybrand/mylocation"
  }
};
const url = new URL(_window.location.href);
const components = url.pathname.split('/').slice(-2);

document.getElementById("brand").innerHTML = `<h1>${components[0]}</h1>`;
document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = `<h1>${components[1]}</h1>`;
```

```html
<!-- notice the quoted id expressions -->
<div id="brand"></div>
<div id="location"></div>
```

Comment: Don't think (1) is an issue, direct quote from OP: `the following method, because it renders them only once` - Also id's "technically" don't need to be wrapped in qoutes [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gv04Lqpz/)

Comment: You might be right, @DarkBee. I was worried I had misunderstood.

Comment: it almost works, 
  const url = new URL(_window.location.href);
const components = url.pathname.split('/').slice(-2);

document.getElementById("specialist").innerHTML = `{% set specialist %}${components[0]}{% endset %}`;
document.getElementById("bezorgen").innerHTML = `{% set bezorgen %}${components[1]}{% endset %}`;

only thing left is how to get the "set" working...

Comment: You can't mix js and twig

Answer (score 1):

twig only solution:
https://www.url.com/service/bikespecialist/trek/amsterdam/

```
{% set brand %}{{ request.url| split('/', 7)[5]| trim('/')  }}{% endset %}
{% set location %}{{ request.url| split('/', 7)[6]| trim('/')  }}{% endset %}
```

in the text

```
   this {{ brand }} bike is awesome, come and buy it at {{ brand }} {{ location }}
```

To all who replied, many thanks! this problem had me bugged for the last couple weeks

and in the case of no brand or location in the url

```
{% set band %}{{ request.url| split('/', 7)[5]| trim('/') |capitalize }}{% endset %} 
{% if brand is empty %}
{% set brand %}qualitybikes {% endset %}
{% endif %}
{% set loation %}{{ request.url| split('/', 7)[6]| trim('/') |capitalize }}{% endset %}
{% if location is empty %}
{% set location %}entire country {% endset %}
{% endif %}
```